# Graph Endpoint to get Application identity details returned in CreatedBy property of driveItems?

Tags: sharepoint, identity

I have creating document using CSOM and Powershell at SharePoint Document Lib. When I tied to get the driveItem details of the item I get a set which contains user and appliation.

[Image for Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxyVo.png)

As I need to get the Information regarding the Application using CSOM. Is there any specific end point or any possibilities to get the details?

Comment: Per my knowledge, CSOM does not provide access above the Site Collection level, so you cannot get all the web applications of SharePoint using CSOM.

Comment: Is there any graph endpoints ?